# textbox to allow multi strings for ciphers codes

Tags: c#

i created my custom cyphers that are strings. when i try to run the code `textbox1` is only returning vale of a single code its not appending , eg writing "4 5d" in `textbox1` wont give a value but when i change the code from `string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered);` to `string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher("4", "5d");` its giving result `" take 4 for 5 days"`in texbox2. when i type `4 5d` in textbox1 nothing is showing in textbox2, i need help in making the textbox1 work

***My class code***

```
class MyCipher : ICipherDecipher
{
    private List<Code> alphabet;

    public MyCipher()
    {
        alphabet = new List<Code>();

        alphabet.Add(new Code("4", " take 4"));
        alphabet.Add(new Code("3", " take 3"));
        alphabet.Add(new Code("5d", " for 5 days"));
    }

    public string Cipher(params string[] codes)
    {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string code in codes)
        {
            Code element =
                alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code).SingleOrDefault();

            if (element != null)
            {
                result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();

    }


    class Code
    {
        public string MyCode;
        public string MyDecoded;



        public Code(string code, string decode)
        {
            MyCode = code;
            MyDecoded = decode;
        }

    }
}
```

***Button code where it needs editing***

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ICipherDecipher myCipher;
    public Form1()
    {
        myCipher = new MyCipher();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textToBeCiphered = textBox1.Text;
        string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered);
        textBox2.Text = textCiphered;
    }
}
```

[Nothing is showing after clicking button1  - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KUEs.png)

Comment: i am new guys , i need your help, thank you

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but I would suggest using a Dictionary rather than a List to accomplish the feat your working at, as it will give you much better performance, for ciphering.

Comment: thank you, i will try to do so

Comment: you also wouldn't need the code class as Dictionary is inherently constructed around pairs. So you'd have a Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: So i will implement the dictionary in button click event?

Comment: You implement the Dictionary on the construction of your Cipher class:
alphabet = new Dictionary<string,string>();

            alphabet.Add("4", " take 4");
            alphabet.Add("3", " take 3");
            alphabet.Add("5d", " for 5 days");

Then when you look up the value just do this:

if (alphabet.ContainsKey(code))
   result.Append(alphabet[code]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're entering one single string, not multiple strings, so it's doing a lookup in your alphabet for "4 5d" and not splitting those into "4", "5d". I suggest changing that argument to just `string[] codes` not  `params string[] codes` and doing a split on your input so that it gets split by spaces.

In summary:

Change this:

```
 public string Cipher(params string[] codes)
```

To:

```
 public string Cipher(string[] codes)
```

And change this:

```
string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered);
```

To:

```
string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered.Split(' '));
```

For constructing the dictionary:

```
alphabet = new Dictionary<string,string>(); 
alphabet.Add("4", " take 4"); 
alphabet.Add("3", " take 3"); 
alphabet.Add("5d", " for 5 days");
```

Then looking up the code will look like this:

```
if (alphabet.ContainsKey(code))
   result.Append(alphabet[code]);
```

Instead of this:

```
Code element =
        alphabet.Where(x => x.MyCode == code).SingleOrDefault();

if (element != null)
{
    result.Append(element.MyDecoded);
}
```

Comment: how do i use the split method on that part, i am failing to do so, how do i split in this case

Comment: Change the line:

string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered);

To:

string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered.Split(" "));

And also remove that 'params' word in the argument section of your Cipher function as specified in my answer.

Comment: Also, just clarified the changes in my answer.

Comment: i am getting an error can not convert string to char in Split(" "))

Comment: Thank you its working now used single ' ' instead of " " , thank you

Comment: Cool, yea that was my mistake, forgot Split uses chars and chars need single quotes.

Comment: and also if im not using class how will i call the dictionary on texbox1 like here `string textCiphered = myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered.Split(' ')); ` what will i do?

Comment: Also i wont be using the `foreach (string code in codes)` statement???

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly with the dictionary now

Answer (score 0):

Are you splitting up the input string? The textbox.Text gives out the string of "4 5d" in your case, not "4","5d". In this case, it seems that you want to check each 'part' of the string for the cipher. The function [String.Split(" ")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=netcore-3.1) should get that job done as it splits the string by the spaces into a string array.

Comment: how do i use the split method on that part, i am failing to do so

Comment: I would change textToBeCiphered to a string array, and make it equal to textBox1.Text.Split(" "); You would then have to change the next line to equal to myCipher.Cipher(textToBeCiphered[0],textToBeCiphered[1]). Note: this means that it will only check the first two 'words'.